# Problems with Groovy Doc

Tags: grails, javadoc, grails-2.4, groovydoc

I'm trying to generate Java documentation of a Grails 2.4.3 project but I'm getting an error and nothing is generated.

```
grails doc --verbose
```

The result is:

```
[groovydoc] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.SourceBuffer.getSnippet(SourceBuffer.java:79)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.getJavaDocCommentsBeforeNode(SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.java:620)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.visitVariableDef(SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.java:346)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.visitNode(TraversalHelper.java:279)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.openingVisit(TraversalHelper.java:530)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.accept_v_AllChildren_v(TraversalHelper.java:450)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.SourceCodeTraversal.accept(SourceCodeTraversal.java:127)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.acceptSiblings(TraversalHelper.java:506)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.acceptChildren(TraversalHelper.java:517)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.accept_v_AllChildren_v(TraversalHelper.java:451)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.SourceCodeTraversal.accept(SourceCodeTraversal.java:127)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.acceptSiblings(TraversalHelper.java:506)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.accept_FirstChild_v_RestOfTheChildren(TraversalHelper.java:459)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.SourceCodeTraversal.accept(SourceCodeTraversal.java:195)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.acceptSiblings(TraversalHelper.java:506)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.treewalker.TraversalHelper.process(TraversalHelper.java:554)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.parseGroovy(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.getClassDocsFromSingleSource(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:83)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.processFile(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:213)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.buildTree(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:174)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyDocTool.add(GroovyDocTool.java:84)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovydoc.execute(Groovydoc.java:444)
[groovydoc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:327)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:272)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:149)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:207)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:66)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at _GrailsDocs$_run_closure6.doCall(_GrailsDocs.groovy:152)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:151)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1155)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1275)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1169)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:84)
[groovydoc]     at _GrailsDocs$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsDocs.groovy:102)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:151)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1155)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1275)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1169)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1256)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1275)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1169)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:151)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:84)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
[groovydoc]     at _GrailsDocs$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsDocs.groovy:97)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:151)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1155)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1275)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1169)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
[groovydoc]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
[groovydoc]     at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[groovydoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[groovydoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[groovydoc]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
(...)
```

I've tried to search it but nobody else seems to experience this problem.

Comment: Gdoc file causing this error may help answering this question